# Select only one line in TortoiseHGs chunk selection for commit

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

In TortoiseHG there is this chunk-selection for your local changes. How can I select only one line from these chunks to commit? I had this problem a few times now and it's quite annoying you can't select only one line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TortoiseHG doesn't support this. However you can still get the same functionality with mercurial CLI by setting `[ui] interface = curses` in your hgrc and then `hg commit -i`. It will invoke a ncurses based window in which you can select/deselect the individual hunks and lines using spacebar. This is much more powerful than what THG offers.

[image: interactive commit]

Comment: The request for this feature is tracked here: https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issues/3319/per-line-chunk-selection